# Why is the verb not conjugated in the plural?

Tags: conjugation

A text I am studying has the sentence

> Verboten war damals vieles.

I cannot understand why this correct. I would expect it to be

> Verboten waren damals vieles.

because the subject is clearly plural since the sentence is talking about many things. In English this is like saying, "At the time many things *was* forbidden." Clearly incorrect.

Comment: I'd rather say it corresponds to "at the time much was(!) forbidden".

Comment: When you say "jeder Deutsche" you are talking about around 80 Million people, depending on your definition of "Deutscher". Nevertheless the number of "jeder" is singular, in contrast to "alle (Deutschen)", which is plural, and I think, in English it works the same way.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is that, in German, *vieles* is singular. This can be seen (although perhaps not absolutely clearly) by the fact that it ends in the neuter singular ending: *-es*.

That might sound like a bit of a cop-out, but natural languages are organic, and don't tend to be perfectly logical.

But just to help clear things up a bit more, *vieles* is one of a group of similar words, such as *alles, nichts, einiges* and *manches*, all of which are singular and neuter by default (although they can be declined in the plural in specific cases, as explained in @Cacambo's answer).

In a way, *vieles* can be translated both as *much* or *many*, as can be seen here, but is singular in both cases:

> Vieles ist noch unklar
>   Much is still unclear
>
> Er hat mir vieles erzählt
>   He told me many things

Comment: Actually one could translate "Er hat mir vieles erzählt" very well as a singular  ("He told me much/a lot"). Your English translation has a literal German equivalent, after all.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Apparently my English is getting rusty, because I didn't think that was valid English. The sad thing is – English is my native language! (I did also just check with two friends, and you're totally right, haha)

Comment: If you had insisted that I'm wrong I would have believed you... it does sound a bit odd, one would expect a specification ("He told me much about the affair" or the like). But the German is also a bit odd without an addition ("... vieles, das mir neu war").

Answer (score 4):

It is the neuter singular form of the pronoun "viel" ("much, many") ([source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vieles)). It is appropriate in this isolated sentence. Imagine as an English translation: "**A lot *was*** forbidden."

"Viele" would be a plural form. This also is grammatically correct but it is an adjective (more complicated than I as a native speaker thought, as it can be [a weak and a strong form](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viele#German)). Therefore, it is expected to refer to some noun. The noun may be explicit, as in:

> Verboten waren damals viele alltägliche Handlungen.

Or it might be implied, as in:

> Schusswaffen, Hiebwaffen, Stichwaffen – verboten waren damals viele.

The implied noun here is "Waffen".